# VB Form Not Holding Format

Tags: vb.net

In the design window, I have my controls formatted one way, but when I run my program, the formatting changes. The window looks larger and the digit button is no longer aligned. I have no clue how to fix this. I am taking an intro level course, so I can't fix this with code. When I wrote my first couple of programs, I didn't have an issue with resizing, but for the last two or three, they never hold their size. 
[My Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUlbN.png)

Answer (score 1):

the above issue please check the anchor tag of each control it should be Top left.
**To hold the control position**

> 1 Add panel control to form then dock it to form
>   2 Add the other
>   control it will hold the control position as well